# qt QWebView fails on loading jQuery page

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit, qwebpage, qwebelement

I have been struggling this problem lately and couldn’t find any solution for that. So, I’d appreciate if you could really look into this.

There is a target website which runs JQuery when I click on a specific button. When I connect to the signals of QWebView and QNetworkAccessManager, I see the it hangs loading jquery_modules.min_22190.js. I have no clue why this happens.

Here is a minimal code that you can try and see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rooelcjbcl9qus/minimal_webview.zip

Last thing that I see in the logs:

```
finished  "Unknown error" , code: 0  QUrl( "http://www2.thewebsite.be/nl/js/jquery/jquery_modules.min_22190.js" )  
Header 1 = "Date" :  "Sat, 26 Jul 2014 08:50:55 GMT"
Header 2 = "Server" :  "Apache"
Header 3 = "X-Frame-Options" :  "SAMEORIGIN"
Header 4 = "Cache-Control" :  "max-age=604800"
Header 5 = "Expires" :  "Sat, 02 Aug 2014 08:50:55 GMT"
Header 6 = "Vary" :  "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"
Header 7 = "Content-Encoding" :  "gzip"
Header 8 = "P3P" :  "CP='NOI DSP COR PSAo PSDo'"
Header 9 = "Keep-Alive" :  "timeout=5, max=200"
Header 10 = "Connection" :  "Keep-Alive"
Header 11 = "Content-Type" :  "text/html; charset=iso-8859-15"
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: RUn Wireshark and follow the TCP stream for this request.  Should give you something to go on.

Comment: Why wireshark? The webpage loads perfect with Chrome. I din't get the idea behind it. Thanks.

Comment: You may find you're getting an unexpected response or HTTP error behind the scenes that QWebView is choking on.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem: `http://www2.thewebsite.be/nl/js/jquery/jquery_modules.min_22190.js` not found. Try this: https://github.com/brcontainer/qt-helper/tree/master/net/network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by moving to Qt 5.3. The above mentioned problem is not reproducible there.

Comment: which version of Qt (and QWebKit) were you using?